# Alignment of bandsaw fence/knuckle

Tags: measurements, machining

I'm looking for what I might be missing in trying to align the fence on my bandsaw. I have a Laguna Tools 18|Bx 3HP 220V 18″ Bandsaw, specifically a MBAND18BX2203. When I let them know the alignment was off, they were super cool and sent me a new aluminum fence. However, my vertical alignment is way off.

[image: the problem]

The problem isn't the fence itself.

[image: nice flat surface and fence]

I'm worried then about the knuckle and rail. Hitting the rail with calipers, I see that I'm off by a bit of a mm (0.68, or 12.93 at one side and 13.61 mm at the other), but that doesn't explain the difference. (See pic below)

[image]

I'm curious if anyone else has had this problem and how I can adjust the knuckle's vertical dimensions or rail.

The fence is also not horizontally aligned.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ok -- sorry I missed this. [The manual](https://go.rockler.com/tech/band-saw-18bx-2203_rev2_962017-manual.pdf) addressed this pretty well. [image]